# How to animate Angular drag-drop elements when appending new ones to the list

Tags: angular, animation, drag-and-drop

Animating Angular drag-drop items is pretty simple. However, a common use-case is adding draggable items to a droplist when the user scrolls to the bottom. "Lazy loading"

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dd-data-bug?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.ts) I've created to demonstrate new draggable items.

**How can I animate new elements as they are appended to the list?**

When scrolled to the bottom I simply push new elements `this.todo.push(...temp);` but need to animate them into the DOM.

Comment: We got Angular Animations that perfectly handle insertions, removals, state changes etc. https://medium.com/@sergeygultyayev/animations-in-angular-756e1d59e385

Answer (score 2):

> How can I animate new elements as they are appended to the list?

You may achieve this by adding classes to animate on the newly pushed objects dynamically.

[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dd-data-bug-fsapj9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.ts) I've created from your Stackblitz

In the `mockPaginate()` method i have added a new property to the array of objects

```
  mockPaginate() {
    // mock data
    let temp = Array(10)
      .fill(1)
      .map((_) => {
        return faker.lorem.word();
      })
      .map((item) => ({ content: item, scssProp: 'red' }));

    this.todo.push(...temp);

    // Set a timer to remove the scssProp property after 1 second
    setTimeout(() => {
      temp.forEach((item) => {
        item.scssProp = ''; // Remove the scssProp property
      });
    }, 1000);

    console.log(this.todo);
  }
```

`scssProp: 'red'` this value is passed as a class in html and can be used in scss to add styles and related animations

You may also add animations like

```
  animations: [
    trigger('someAnimation', [
      state('in', style({ opacity: 1 })),
      transition(':enter', [
        animate(
          500,
          keyframes([
            style({ opacity: 0, offset: 0 }),
            style({ opacity: 0.25, offset: 0.25 }),
            style({ opacity: 0.5, offset: 0.5 }),
            style({ opacity: 0.75, offset: 0.75 }),
            style({ opacity: 1, offset: 1 }),
          ])
        ),
      ]),
    ]),
  ]
```

and add the changes to html like

```
        <div [@someAnimation]="'in'" class="example-box {{item.scssProp}}" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>
          {{item.content}}
        </div>
```

Note: I've modified the input data to be an array of objects of type `{ content: string, scssProp: string }[]` instead of `string[]` to enable passing a custom prop as a class to animate the objects. I'm removing the class after 1 second in the `setTimeout` just to show the effect of being animated.

Comment: Hi @Sourav, thanks for this great answer. But that animates the entire group of new items. Can your approach animate each new item?